# how effective creating 2 database with same content?

Tags: mysql

I'm in a dilemma if creating redundant database will speed up the access considering only the CRUD factor.

Is it effective to create a dedicated DB for creating/updating/deleting records 
and a separate DB for viewing only?

Currently using MySQL.

Comment: I think it's a good idea. Here we have 3 servers , and 2 of them have only views do server 3. So we can store more databases on those 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called Write masters with Read slaves. Check out MySQL replication. You'll find an interesting document [here](https://www.percona.com/live/london-2014/sessions/high-availability-disaster-recovery-and-extreme-read-scaling-using-binlog-servers) (check out the slides) - but you probably won't be needing the level of availability of Booking.com, but hey, who knows? :-).

There are many different replication/HA topologies, but this will give you a start. Also, see [here](http://www.clusterdb.com/) (Andrew Morgan is the author of MySQL Cluster).